# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null even though I have the right element ID referenced

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, typeerror

I keep receiving the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" error message, even thought I've properly labeled my form element with "id="myForm" and am attempting to grab the form via document.getElementById('myForm').

HTML:

```
       <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Bookmark Your Favorite Sites</h2>
        <form id="myForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Site Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-conrol" id="siteName" placeholder="Website Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Site URL</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-conrol" id="siteUrl" placeholder="Website URL">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Listen for form submit
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', saveBookmark);

//Save bookmark
function saveBookmark(e){
   console.log("It works"); //Test to see if it works

//Prevent form from submitting
e.preventDefault();
}
```

I expect to see "It works" logged in the console, but instead I get the error described above.

Comment: Is that code running before the element exists?

Comment: That was it. Moved my script down from the <head> element to bottom of the <body>.